# Interactive Broker: How to get Account Code for my demo-session in TWS?

Tags: interactive-brokers

I have been trying to connect to IB TWS using C++ APIs. It looks like I need to know my Account-Code tough to connect with the APIs, but I don't know where to find it.

```
{
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 7497,
    "clientId": 888,      # this should be a random number for the Demo
    "accountCode": "?"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you open TWS you can find the account-code for your Demo session on the top-right. (light blue box in the picture)[image]